# How to add styles to RichHtmlField when master pages cannot be edited?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ribbon, blog, richhtmlfield, style-library

I have a problem. I have SharePoint Designer 2013 I want to add a style in the ribbon:

[image]

Many posts suggest to edit master pages, but in my case this is not possible as my Sharepoint web site has this functionality disabled in the parent site. There is no way i can enable this.

How to do?